Origin of "legacy media" to designate older media with an alleged "liberal bias"
Newer media, like Twitter/X, refer to "legacy media." Is it known when/where this phrase originated?
I am seeing the expression "legacy media" only recently. By definition, any media that existed before the newer media like Twitter would be part of "legacy media".  In the computer world, "legacy code" or "legacy applications" are those that aren't worked on to improve them and are only maintained as they are until they are retired from use.
Is it known when/where this phrase originated?
For examples, let me google that for you. It can be seen that this term is largely used by conservatives to allege a "liberal bias" in traditional media.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about the English language.

Twitter was renamed X in July 2023, so in actual fact your question could be misinterpreted and is therefore ambiguous. Is the old Twitter also part of "legacy media"? Define what you think is legacy media, and include some examples. P.S You vote to reopen your question.

Just trying to help, I very happily edit questions that I retain are on topic and deserve to be answered, and I have helped to reopen hundreds of closed posts in the past. If you're not interested in accepting advice or improving a post, that's no skin off my back. P.S Twitter as a brandname no longer exists, and it's spelled with a capital letter (see your title).

From Ngram, you can see that "legacy media" appears recently, less than 20 years ago, in connection with emergence of social media. The term "traditional media" that came into use decades earlier is still much more frequent than "legacy media".

It seems to have come from a computing term for old systems (MW), but it's an obvious extension of use with a similar meaning. Such terms for traditional media are often mildly derogatory, like "snail mail" for conventional postage, "dead trees" for print media, or "plain old telephone service".

It would help to give an example or two in context.

Telling people to go googling for examples is not the same thing as providing examples. Edit this to include the actual examples.

The Google 2-gram graph flatlines before about 1990, then takes off. Reasonable research to provide.

The history of particular expressions being used in contemporary political polemics really doesn't belong on this site at all. Maybe on Politics.SE?

There's nothing special about the phrase "legacy media". "Legacy" is a general term used for outdated or obsolete variants of something. When personal computers became commonplace, mainframes and minicomputers became "legacy computers". This is the relevant definition from M-W:

of, relating to, associated with, or carried over from an earlier time, technology, business, etc.

OED has the following definition (behind a paywall):

Designating something left over from a previous era but still in active existence.

So "legacy media" just means traditional media (printed newspapers/magazines, TV, and radio) when used in relation to modern online media.
This is a relatively recent usage, OED's earliest citation is from 1998. There's a related sense for businesses or industries that have become obsolete, usually because they're been replaced by digital or online technologies; it only dates to 1984.

This question is ONLY about media, not businesses or industries.  First off, MOST hard copy media have gone partly or wholly electronic - so the designation is not based on technology. This designation is overwhelmingly made by right wingers to denigrate media such as the New York Times, founded in 1851 and calls itself "the Newspaper of record" for maintaining journalistic standards.  Elon Musk denigrates "legacy media" almost every day on his platform - HIS standard of journalism is to post an image of a hammer when speaker Pelosi's elderly husband was attacked with a hammer. @barmar

I edited the question to make my intent clear,

I don't think there's anything in the term that implies liberal bias. Wall Street Journal and Fox News are legacy media, no one would accuse them of being liberal. If some people pervert the term in this way, that's their personal ideosyncracy, I don't think it's a common interpretation.

Fox News is "legacy media" ?- that would be news to Greg Gutfeld .https://www.foxnews.com/opinion/greg-gutfeld-legacy-media-less-trusted-than-week-old-tuna-salad  it largely means established media that maintain journalistic standards, @barmar

That's a bastardisation of the term, by biased reporters. It's like the way Trump uses the word "great" in his MAGA slogan.

A better analogy might be the way conservatives use "liberal" as an insult, as in "San Francisco liberal".

yes!!!!!!!!!  the Question is = when was "legacy media" coined as a hate meme - the same way as "liberal" ?  In Texas, "liberal" was bad enough, but "Ted Kennedy Librul" was VERY bad.  nowadays "San Francisco librul" throws in homophobia too. @barmar

@Barmar I've exclusively heard this term being used by right-wingers as an insult directed at the "mainstream media." Specifically, people right-wing enough that they don't much like Fox or the WSJ either.

@SK In that case, I'm with the comments that say this isn't a question about the language. This is more a question about politics, and about how people turn phrases into dog whistles. An even better analogy would be "critical race theory". It was an academic term until conservatives decided to use it to mean "teaching about the history of race == teaching white kids to be ashamed of their history"

@alphabet I disagree that this is exclusively used as an insult. See these results from Google Ngrams https://www.google.com/search?q=%22legacy%20media%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2022,cd_max:2022&lr=lang_en None of them seem to be using it in a pejorative way at all, just distinguishing traditional from modern media.

The NYTimes is "legacy media" the same way Newton,, Gauss, Euler et al are "legacy math".  Musk explicitly suggests "legacy media" will go away, unable to compete with his platform @Barmar  Right wingers exult that Washington post is in financial trouble.  They really think the immediacy of media like twitter (an immediacy made possible because of lack of quality control) will make the prestige press wither away.

It's the legacy media themselves who are labeling anyone who doesn't agree with their "liberal" globalisation-fueled plans as "far right-wing". Not that political left / right is a very relevant concept here - it's mostly globalists vs nationalists (and "big State" vs "light touch" at the level of countries and taxpayers). The EU is itching to control X and AI, but Musk's having none of it.

@SK Of course Musk says legacy media will go away. But not because of their politics, but because of the economics of online media. It's like Henry Ford predicting that the horse and buggy industry would die.

Legacy is not generally a 'term used for outdated or obsolete variants of something'. It has these implications only in the relatively recent usage it has acquired in the IT contexts. The term, however, has a long history of being used without any disparaging implications, and continues to be so used outside the IT (and related) settings.

@jsw29 My answer clearly points out that the earliest citations are only 40 years old.

@Barmar, yes, the answer does acknowledge that 'the earliest citations are only 40 years old', but it does not make it clear that this is true only of this, relatively marginal usage. The answer leaves the impression that this is the only way the word is used, while it is, in fact, several steps removed from its primary use, which has centuries of history (e.g. 'the will provides for a £100000 legacy to so-and-so'). This may be obvious to you (and so not in need of being spelled out), but there are bound to be visitors to this page to whom it is not.

I didn't think it was necessary to state that explicitly. Most words have different definitions, which have different histories of usage.

I thought when I said "this is a ... recent usage" it would be obvious that I was only talking about this sense, not all the other meanings of the word.
